# How do I change the text of a label that is inside a usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, label, wpf-controls

I've just started working on a WPF project. I have no experience with XAML at all. Past projects have been Windows Forms.

So down to my question: How do I change the text of a label that is inside a user control?
The user control in question is this:

[image: User control]

This bar will be reused on all of the windows (excluding the MainWindow) in the application.
The Header label is what I would like to change. Preferably I would like to change this text through XAML.
Here is the code for the control:

```
<Grid x:Name="TopBar" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Background="#FF3C3C3C" MouseLeftButtonDown="TopBar_LeftMouseDown">
   <Label x:Name="Header_L" x:FieldModifier="public" Content="Header" Foreground="#FFF2F2F2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="5,0,5,0" />
   <Classes:PL_Button x:Name="Close_B" Style="{StaticResource customButton}" bgColor="#FF3C3C3C" hoverColor="#FF464646" mouseDownColor="#FF373737" Width="24" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Close_B_Click" Margin="0,0,2,0">
      <Image Source="/Resources/Close_Icon.png" Height="12" Width="12"/>
   </Classes:PL_Button>
</Grid>
```

In the new window the control looks like this:

[image: Control in new window]

...Note: I'm not sure why the close button is missing in the designer but its visible when I run the application...

So here is the XAML that displays the bar.

```
<Grid x:Name="Window_Grid">
    <Controls:PL_TopBar_Control VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

This is the place (if possible) I would like to set the header text. It will just make life easier for me in the long run.
Adding 'Content="Some text"' does add text but it doesn't change the actual header label.
I've done some searching about but much of the results involve changing at runtime or through code (maybe I'm not searching the right things?).

```
<Controls:PL_TopBar_Control VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

I would like if possible to change the label text in the above line.

Thanks

Comment: By concept of usage in WPF, a UserControl should represent data received from a DataContext. Accordingly, all values that depend on external data in it must be attached to the default source `"{Binding SomeProperty}"`. If you need to customize an element through its properties, then you don't need a User Control, but a Custom Control. In it you declare additional Dependency Properties. And set the template with bindings `"{TemplateBinding SomeProperty}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After some playing around I managed to find a solution.
In the user control code (c#) I needed the following:

```
public string? LabelContent
    {
        get => Header_L.Content as string;
        set => Header_L.Content = value;
    }
```

Then In the XAML when im using the control I just needed to use LabelContent to set the label text. like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="Window_Grid">
    <Controls:PL_TopBar_Control VerticalAlignment="Top" LabelContent="Some Text"/>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

XAML is going to take some getting used to...

Comment: You really need to read up on Binding and MVVM.  Without it, WPF and XAML is a whole lot harder.  The idea is that your UserControl has some sort of backing *View-Model* object that serves as its `DataContext`.  You bind the content of controls like the `Label` control to view-model backing properties.  When someone sets one of these properties in the view-model, the setter raises an even (`PropertyChanged`) that makes the `Label` control update its UI with the new value.

Comment: MVVM is an architectural pattern that is typically used in WPF applications. UserControls can expose bindable properties that are bound to properties of view model object. Those view model objects are however provided externally, by value inheritance of the DataContext property. Internally, controls do typically not use view models. They must especially never set their own DataContext, which is a commonly made mistaken. The approach shown here is totally valid.

Comment: In order to make `LabelContent` a bindable property, it must however be declared as a [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0). The underlying `Header_L.Content` property would then be set in the dependency property's PropertyChangedCallback.